# Transforming $[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]$ to $[0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8]$

Tags: interpolation, pattern-recognition

Given the range of negative/positive numbers $[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]$, is there a transformation that gives me $[0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8]$?

Comment: Yes.  Temporarily ignore the details of the range and only notice that it is consecutive integers.  Is there a way to write the second list using the same operation over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Think about powers of $2$.

What is $2^0$?

What is $2^1$?

What is $2^2$?

What is $2^{-1}$?

What is $2^{-2}$?

This should make it apparent. The answer would then be if $A=(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3)$ and $B=(0.125,0.25,0.5,1,2,4,8)$ Then $f:A\to B$ is $b=f(a)=2^a$ for $a\in A$.

Comment: Of course. Thank you. But please, post a regular answer. This site ain't school.